# How can I set the supplementary groups of a process?

Tags: group

I can see the supplementary groups of a process by running `cat /proc/$PID/status` and looking at the `Groups:` line.

How can I modify this value for a process?

I know that these values are normally configured by user in the `/etc/group` file, but changes to that file don't immediately propagate into kernel data structures. I want to know what's done by a userspace program to set these values in the kernel.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a process's supplementary groups with the `setgroups` syscall.

Answer (score 1):

I have specifically made a kernel-module program for doing this.

```
#include <linux/cred.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/moduleparam.h>
#include <linux/pid.h>
#include <linux/pid_namespace.h>
#include <linux/printk.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/uidgid.h>


static int arg_pid=0;
static int arg_gid=0;
static char *arg_act="add";

module_param(arg_pid, int, 0);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(arg_pid, "PID of the process");
module_param(arg_gid, int, 0);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(arg_gid, "GID of the group to add to PID's supplimentary groups");
module_param(arg_act, charp, 0);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(arg_act, "action to perform: add/remove/list/query");

struct pid *pid_struct = NULL;
struct task_struct *task = NULL;
struct cred *real_cd = NULL;
struct cred *effe_cd = NULL;
struct group_info *gi = NULL;
struct group_info *new_gi = NULL;

bool query(int gid, struct group_info *gi){
    for(int x=0; x<gi->ngroups; ++x)
        if(gid==gi->gid[x].val) return true;
    return false;
}

int init_module(void) {
    if(arg_pid==0){
        pr_info("Error: Usage: insmod supgroup.ko arg_pid=## arg_gid=## (arg_act='add/remove/list/query') && rmmod supgroup\n");
        return 0;
    }
    pid_struct = find_get_pid(arg_pid);
    if(pid_struct==NULL){
        pr_info("Error: find_get_pid() failed\n");
        return 0;
    }
    task = pid_task(pid_struct, PIDTYPE_PID);
    if(task==NULL){
        pr_info("Error: pid_task() failed\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if(task->real_cred==NULL){
        pr_info("Error: task->real_cred == NULL\n");
        return 0;
    }
    gi = task->real_cred->group_info;
    if(gi==NULL){
        pr_info("Error: task->real_cred->group_info == NULL\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if(!strcmp(arg_act, "add")){
        if(query(arg_gid, gi)){
            pr_info("GID %d is already in PID %d's supplementary group list\n", arg_gid, arg_pid);
            return 0;
        }
        new_gi = groups_alloc(gi->ngroups+1);
        if(new_gi==NULL){
            pr_info("Error: groups_alloc() failed, out of kernel memory?\n");
            return 0;
        }
        for(int x=0; x<gi->ngroups; ++x)
            new_gi->gid[x] = gi->gid[x];
        new_gi->gid[gi->ngroups].val = arg_gid;
        groups_sort(new_gi);

        // forcefully set group_info
        get_cred((const struct cred *)new_gi);
        *(struct group_info**)(&task->real_cred->group_info) = new_gi;
        *(struct group_info**)(&task->cred->group_info) = new_gi;

        pr_info("Added GID %d to PID %d's supplementary groups\n", arg_gid, arg_pid);
    }else if(!strcmp(arg_act, "remove")){
        if(!query(arg_gid, gi)){
            pr_info("GID %d is not in PID %d's supplementary group list\n", arg_gid, arg_pid);
            return 0;
        }
        new_gi = groups_alloc(gi->ngroups-1);
        if(new_gi==NULL){
            pr_info("Error: groups_alloc() failed, out of kernel memory?\n");
            return 0;
        }
        for(int x=0,y=0; x<gi->ngroups; ++x)
            if(gi->gid[x].val != arg_gid){
                new_gi->gid[y] = gi->gid[x];
                y++;
            }

        // forcefully set group_info
        get_cred((const struct cred *)new_gi);
        *(struct group_info**)(&task->real_cred->group_info) = new_gi;
        *(struct group_info**)(&task->cred->group_info) = new_gi;

        pr_info("Removed GID %d from PID %d's supplementary groups\n", arg_gid, arg_pid);
    }else if(!strcmp(arg_act, "list")){
        pr_info("Listing PID %d's supplementary groups' GIDs: ", arg_pid);
        for(int x=0; x<gi->ngroups; ++x)
            pr_info("%d ", gi->gid[x].val);
        pr_info("Done\n");
    }else if(!strcmp(arg_act, "query")){
        pr_info("GID %d is %s PID %d's supplementary group list\n", arg_gid, query(arg_gid, gi)?"in":"not in", arg_pid);
    }

    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void){}
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Checkout its usage at my Github repo (https://github.com/xuancong84/supgroup).
This is useful for updating supplementary group info for running processes.